# Join List of Map Objects in java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap

Have a two list of Map, should do the dataset joins on those two lists, leftJoin, rightJoin, outerJoin and innerJoin

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class JoinMap {
    public static List<Map<String, Object>> getFirstMap() {
        List<Map<String,  Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String,  Object> dataMap2 = new HashMap<>();
        dataMap2.put("user", "vs");
        dataMap2.put("data1", 12.0);
        dataMap2.put("data2", 42.0);
        dataMap2.put("data3", 32.0);
        data.add(dataMap2);
        Map<String,  Object> dataMap1 = new HashMap<>();
        dataMap1.put("user", "samraj");
        dataMap1.put("data1", 11.0);
        dataMap1.put("data2", 41.0);
        dataMap1.put("data3", 31.0);
        data.add(dataMap1);
        Map<String,  Object> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
        dataMap.put("user", "varghees");
        dataMap.put("data1", 10.0);
        dataMap.put("data2", 40.0);
        dataMap.put("data3", 30.0);
        data.add(dataMap);
        return data;
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> getSecondMap() {
        List<Map<String,  Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String,  Object> dataMap2 = new HashMap<>();
        dataMap2.put("user", "vs");
        dataMap2.put("test1", 12.0);
        dataMap2.put("test2", 42.0);
        dataMap2.put("test3", 32.0);
        data.add(dataMap2);
        Map<String,  Object> dataMap1 = new HashMap<>();
        dataMap1.put("user", "samraj");
        dataMap1.put("test1", 11.0);
        dataMap1.put("test2", 41.0);
        dataMap1.put("test3", 31.0);
        data.add(dataMap1);
        Map<String,  Object> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
        dataMap.put("user", "varghees");
        dataMap.put("test1", 10.0);
        dataMap.put("test2", 40.0);
        dataMap.put("test3", 30.0);
        data.add(dataMap);
        return data;
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> leftJoin(List<Map<String, Object>> map1, List<Map<String, Object>> map2) {

    }
    public static List<Map<String, Object>> rightJoin(List<Map<String, Object>> map1, List<Map<String, Object>> map2) {

    }
    public static List<Map<String, Object>> innerJoin(List<Map<String, Object>> map1, List<Map<String, Object>> map2) {

    }
    public static List<Map<String, Object>> outerJoin(List<Map<String, Object>> map1, List<Map<String, Object>> map2) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> firstMap = getFirstMap();
        List<Map<String, Object>> secondMap = getSecondMap();
    }
}
```

Is there any easy functions available in Java8 to accomplish these methods? I am trying to avoid iterating over data and populate new dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there is. Here’s an example using streams for the inner join. I am assuming we know for a fact that we should join on `"user"` (if not, it’s getting more complicated, but it still can be done).

```
public static List<Map<String, Object>> innerJoin(List<Map<String, Object>> map1, List<Map<String, Object>> map2) {
    return map1.stream().flatMap(m1 -> 
        map2.stream()
                .filter(m2 -> m1.get("user").equals(m2.get("user")))
                .map((Map<String, Object> m2) -> {
                    Map<String, Object> mr = new HashMap<>();
                    mr.putAll(m1);
                    mr.putAll(m2);
                    return mr;
                })
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I hope and think you will be able to take the inspiration and do the others yourself.

Comment: Yes this is nice and worked. If we able to fix other functions i will mark this as solution